# AspNet.WebApi always converts my error responses to text/html

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

Having an ExceptionFilter attribute defined like this:

```
public class HandleExceptionsFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = GetExceptionalResponse(context.Exception);

        base.OnException(context);
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return
            Task.FromResult(GetExceptionalResponse(actionExecutedContext.Exception));
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage GetExceptionalResponse(Exception ex)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ex.Message, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, null),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
        };
    }
}
```

When exception happens I always get bunch of html code wrapping my exception details. What I want is to return only the exception message to the frontend (and send `text/plain` `Content-Type` header). How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type on the content of the response.

```
private HttpResponseMessage GetExceptionalResponse(Exception ex) {
    return new HttpResponseMessage {
        Content = new StringContent(ex.Message, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
    };
}
```

Comment: It wont' change anything. `StringContent` by default sets the content type to `text/plain`.